# mongodb 3.0.2 losing user info on restart

Tags: mongodb

Our mongodb process is killed and restarted at 10am every Saturday. Intermittently we experience problems whereby the user data is lost. To recover we have to recreate all users including the siteUserAdmin.

Running on Linux:

```
2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 15 13:44:51 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is what's in the db log:

```
2015-10-02T18:24:45.413+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from xxx.211.4.30:47728 #300 (159 connections now open)
2015-10-02T18:24:45.439+0100 I ACCESS   [conn300] Successfully authenticated as principal user on mydb
2015-10-02T18:24:45.446+0100 I NETWORK  [conn300] end connection xxx.211.4.30:47728 (158 connections now open)
2015-10-03T10:00:35.013+0100 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2015-10-03T10:00:35.115+0100 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2015-10-03T10:00:35.115+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-10-03T10:00:35.129+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 9
2015-10-03T10:00:35.129+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 10
2015-10-03T10:00:35.195+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2015-10-03T10:00:35.195+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-10-03T10:00:35.195+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-10-03T10:00:35.196+0100 I NETWORK  [conn9] end connection xxx.31.111.22:33093 (157 connections now open)
2015-10-03T10:00:35.196+0100 I NETWORK  [conn107] end connection xxx.163.125.7:62991 (157 connections now open)
2015-10-03T10:00:35.196+0100 I NETWORK  [conn22] end connection xxx.11.66.91:39150 (157 connections now open)
2015-10-03T10:00:35.196+0100 I NETWORK  [conn128] end connection xxx.39.75.39:52306 (157 connections now open)
...
2015-10-03T10:00:35.199+0100 I NETWORK  [conn247] end connection xxx.31.203.10:48608 (155 connections now open)
2015-10-03T10:00:35.199+0100 I NETWORK  [conn245] end connection xxx.31.203.10:48602 (154 connections now open)
2015-10-03T10:00:35.199+0100 I NETWORK  [conn264] end connection xxx.31.203.10:54803 (153 connections now open)
2015-10-03T10:00:35.199+0100 I NETWORK  [conn248] end connection xxx.31.203.10:48203 (154 connections now open)
2015-10-03T10:00:35.216+0100 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-10-03T10:00:35.233+0100 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: final commit...
2015-10-03T10:00:35.263+0100 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] journalCleanup...
2015-10-03T10:00:35.263+0100 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] removeJournalFiles
2015-10-03T10:00:35.352+0100 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] Terminating durability thread ...
2015-10-03T10:00:35.438+0100 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread stopped
2015-10-03T10:00:35.438+0100 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread stopped
2015-10-03T10:00:35.438+0100 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-10-03T10:00:35.455+0100 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-10-03T10:00:35.463+0100 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-10-03T10:00:35.463+0100 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] dbexit:  rc: 0
2015-10-03T10:20:04.575+0100 I CONTROL  ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2015-10-03T10:20:04.629+0100 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=xxx/journal
2015-10-03T10:20:04.629+0100 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-10-03T10:20:04.655+0100 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2015-10-03T10:20:04.655+0100 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2015-10-03T10:20:04.656+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=17795 port=27017 dbpath=xxx/db2 64-bit host=xxx
2015-10-03T10:20:04.656+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2015-10-03T10:20:04.656+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running on a NUMA machine.
2015-10-03T10:20:04.656+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          We suggest launching mongod like this to avoid performance problems:
2015-10-03T10:20:04.656+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **              numactl --interleave=all mongod [other options]
2015-10-03T10:20:04.656+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2015-10-03T10:20:04.656+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.2
2015-10-03T10:20:04.656+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6201872043ecbbc0a4cc169b5482dcf385fc464f
2015-10-03T10:20:04.656+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux build6.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-10-03T10:20:04.656+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-10-03T10:20:04.656+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "xxx/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.2/bin/mongodb.conf", processManagement: { fork: true }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "xxx/db2", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "xxx/mongod.log" } }
2015-10-03T10:20:04.827+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2015-10-03T10:20:05.045+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from xxx.11.239.14:36968 #1 (1 connection now open)
2015-10-03T10:20:05.071+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from xxx.3.50.33:36240 #2 (2 connections now open)
2015-10-03T10:20:05.139+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from xxx.39.144.16:47416 #3 (3 connections now open)
...
2015-10-03T10:20:16.730+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from xxx.31.203.10:51281 #67 (67 connections now open)
2015-10-03T10:20:16.843+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from xxx.31.203.10:51282 #68 (68 connections now open)
2015-10-03T10:20:16.862+0100 I ACCESS   [conn68]  authenticate db: mydb { authenticate: 1, user: "user", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-10-03T10:20:16.862+0100 I ACCESS   [conn68] Failed to authenticate user@mydb with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed UserNotFound Could not find user user@mydb
```

A little at a loss to understand the cause of this and would welcome good advice.

Comment: why do you restart mongo in the first place?

Comment: Are you sure you are authenticating against the correct database?

Comment: The problem is intermittent. Okay 3 times in 4. Restarts are connected to server reboots. I am unable to recreate with kill.

Comment: how do you create the users?

Comment: Do all your replica sets have the same config? Can you check `db.getSiblingDB('admin').system.version.findOne({ "_id" : "authSchema"}).currentVersion` on all members of the replica set and confirm what versions are reported? I noticed you have a MONGO-CR authentication failure, so perhaps the missing users were created (or upgraded) to use the default SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication in MongoDB 3.0.